# печать документа из php

Tags: php, phpword

как вывести файл на принтер `$document->save('Template_full'.$today.'.docx');`
использую phpWord

Answer (score 1):

Отправить файл сразу на принтер через браузер нельзя.
Можно:

**Отправить файл в виде вывода** (чтобы он сразу открылся в браузере, если браузер поддерживает), а далее пользователь смог бы отправить его на печать, не сохраняя.

```
$filename="print_me.docx";
header( "Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-word" );
header( 'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$filename );

$phpWordObject->save( "php://output" );
```

**Отправить файл на принтер**, подключенный к серверу, на котором работает ваш PHP сценарий. Для этого можно вызвать команду lp

```
exec('lp /path/to/file.doc');
```

Для этого на сервере должны быть установлены все необходимые приложения, чтобы файл можно было распечатать из формата Word. В противном случае его нужно будет предварительно подготовить для печати.

Comment: вот такая ошибка Warning: rename(): Cannot rename a file across wrapper types in /var/www/vhosts/u0005768.plsk.regruhosting.ru/pd.ulikes.ru/assets/PHPWord/PHPWord/Template.php on line 114

Comment: Имеет смысл привести код, который вызвал ошибку. Предполагаю, что вы пытаетесь задать имя файлу, который отправляете на вывод

Comment: $filename="print_me.docx";
header( "Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-word" );
header( 'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$filename );

$document->save( "php://output" );